# AngularJS Wizard with dynamic steps

Tags: angularjs

I have to implement a wizard, where each step is a single input field.
Everything is wrapped inside an accordion with section headers.

The user, after filling the input and pressing Enter, should navigate the wizard field by field. Only the current field is editable, while the other ones are readonly (the user can anytime change a previously filled input, by clicking it, moving the current pointer to it).

I was wondering what could be the best approach to design this system, considering that the whole wizard structure changes in dependence of different user inputs.

I have found a tutorial using ui-router (http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router), with a fixed number of steps, but my requirements are to show the current input edit box inside the accordion, not in a fixed "ui-views" placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-autoFields-bootstrap

It's a module that allows you to render forms from Metadata. So essentially, you can change the Metadata you provide dynamically to change the forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really a good start. To implement a field-by-field wizard I am wondering if working with ng-if makes sense to show only one field at time.